# No visible @interface for "DiceView" declares the selector "showDiceNumber."

Tags: objective-c, ios7, selector

Will someone else please review my code ? There has to be something wrong. No answers have worked yet. Anybody any other ideas? I received the error message in the title at the bottom of SecondViewController.m. I'm not exactly sure why and I tried looking it up, but I can't find anything. I thought that I declared what the "showDiceNumber" was, but maybe not. This is the second page to my app, but that shouldn't be causing the problem because the error is in the second view controller. I would really appreciate someone reviewing the code and helping me in this situation. Thanks a lot!

(By the way, I took out the super view did load and drawing codes because they were useless and took up too much room. They are in my coding in Xcode though.)

SecondViewController.h -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DiceView.h"

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *rollButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sumLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet DiceView *firstDiceView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet DiceView *secondDiceView;

@end
```

SecondViewController.m -

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "DiceDataController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}


- (IBAction)rollClicked:(id)sender {

DiceDataController *diceController = [[DiceDataController alloc] init];

int firstNumber = [diceController getDiceNumber];
int secondNumber = [diceController getDiceNumber];

[self.firstDiceView showDiceNumber:firstNumber];  <---- error*
[self.secondDiceView showDiceNumber:secondNumber];  <----- error*
}

@end
```

DiceView.h -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DiceView : UIView

#pragma mark - Properties

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *diceImageView;

#pragma mark - Methods

- (void)showDiceNumber:(int)num;

@end
```

DiceView.m-

```
#import "DiceView.h"

@implementation DiceView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code

}
return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code

   // create uiimageview and assign it to our property
   self.diceImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,       self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];

    // add the imageview to the view
    [self addSubview:self.diceImageView];

}
return self;
}

- (void)showDiceNumber:(int)num
{
// construct filename based on input param
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dice%d.png", num];

// set the image to the uiimageview
self.diceImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
}
@end
```

DiceDataController.h-

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DiceDataController : NSObject

-(int)getDiceNumber; 

@end
```

DiceDataController.m-

```
#import "DiceDataController.h"

@implementation DiceDataController

-(int)getDiceNumber
{
int r = (arc4random() % 6) +1;
return r;
}
@end
```

Comment: Will someone please help? It is probably something stupid but I can't find the error.

Comment: @MrHaze could you take a look? You have helped me before.

Comment: What you posted looks correct. Sometimes Xcode gets confused. Try closing your project and quitting Xcode. Then restart and see if it helps.

Comment: I tried that. The red exclamation mark errors came up again, so there has to be something wrong. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @rmaddy any other ideas? I really need this solved. Much appreciation.

Comment: Did you set the custom class of the view as "DiceView"?

Comment: Possibly. I have a DiceView.m and DiceView.h. I'm not really sure what you mean (beginner.) The subclass was UIView

Comment: What I mean is in the storyboard. Make sure you have set the correct custom class for the views, which are firstDiceView and secondDiceView, as DiceDivew.

Comment: yeah I just checked. Both have the custom class as DiceView

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the code in this question.

I've seen errors like this caused by the inclusion of odd non-printing characters in source code.

I'm not aware of a method of displaying them in Xcode, but if you open the .h and .m files in an editor like text wrangler (free) and turn on "show invisibles", you might see unusual stuff - possibly near or around the import statements.

If they exist, deleting them should solve the problem.

I'm not sure how they get there - it's either odd stuff that gets picked up when you copy and paste from the web, or possibly some keyboard shortcut in Xcode is very similar to some keyboard shortcut that types a non breaking simplified Chinese em space or whatever it is.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I wouldn't even know what to look for as this is all new for me. Any ideas on the unusual stuff I would need to delete?

Comment: It would be obvious really - anything that's not a space, tab or newline character.

Comment: I have it, but I don't know what I'm looking for still. Should I edit post and paste the text wrangle show invisibles code?

Comment: I don't think they'd show up, without a screenshot? New lines are at the end of every line, spaces are dots and tabs are kind of dashy, I think. Look for big diamond shapes or something that you can't see anywhere else.

Comment: hmm I can't post screenshot because I don't have 10 rep yet. I don't see anything unusual though

Comment: Well, it was only a guess :(

Comment: You could upload the project onto github or something? Then anyone can take a look at it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with github. IS there a way I could send the project to you? Do you have an email or can you create a new account?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the last way you can try, silencing the error but may cause app crash. Add this to SecondViewController.m:

```
@interface DiceView (IShouldHaveThis)

- (void)showDiceNumber:(int)num;

@end
```

By redeclaring the method in a category it will silent the error (that was a warning on old time, so can be silenced) but you should throughly check your code to be extremely sure that is is actually working.

Comment: what do I do with the UIView that was there? It was @interface DiceView : UIView. Also, what is (IShouldHaveThis) ?

Comment: @user3496401 That is a category declaration which does not require the `UIView` part.

Comment: it didn't work. Now I have 4 errors at the bottom instead of 2

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
#import DiceView.h
```

in SecondViewController.m

or perhaps your Xcode project file is messed up and you should just create a new Project and copy the source code files into it.

Comment: I just tried it, it didn't work. Now there are 3 of the same erros on the last three line of code at the bottom of SecondViewController.m

Comment: Three errors? It sounds like perhaps you have something messed up with the Xcode project file. What's the new error message that showed up after you added the #import?

Comment: the error is gone now, i guess Xcode got confused. The other errors are still there though